# 403 error while sending a POST request using Karate in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api, http-status-code-403, karate

I am able to access an endpoint using POST request in Postman.
But if I am trying the same using Karate in eclipse I get 403 error. Below is the snapshot.

```
1 > POST http://localhost:8080/MyEndPoint
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Content-Length: 86
1 > Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
1 > Host: localhost:8080
1 > Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_221)
{"credRelFreeIncome":10,"interestIncome":2,"internalExpectedLoss":3,"nonCredIncome":5}
12:35:52.974 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 
45.54
1 < 403
1 < Cache-Control: no-cache
1 < Content-Type: text/html
1 < Content-length: 14520
1 < Server: Zscaler/5.7
```

I have set the necessary proxy settings in karate-config.js - karate.configure('proxy', 'myworkingproxy:8080'), but still doesn't work.

Spring security is not implemented in project yet, so i suppose its not about CSRF token either.

**Curl URL which works in Postman:**
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/getPricingCalculation/getRoE \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 6e9c0433-3977-4612-b989-f2a920e34a86' \
  -d '{
  "credRelFreeIncome": 10,
  "interestIncome": 2,
  "internalExpectedLoss": 3,
  "nonCredIncome": 5
}'

**Karate feature file - which gives 403 error**

Background:
        * url 'http://localhost:8080'
        * header Content-Type = 'application/json'

Scenario:
    Given path '/getPricingCalculation/getRoE'
    And request { "credRelFreeIncome": 10, "interestIncome": 2,   "internalExpectedLoss": 3, "nonCredIncome": 5 }
   When method POST
   Then status 200

Can anyone help please?

Best Regards,
Abhi

Comment: You most certainly are missing a header. So please study the P*stman request and compare with what you are sending with Karate, take the help of the server-side team if you need to. Edit your question with a cURL command / export that can provide better info, or follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks for response Peter. Its the most simple Post request with just one header Content-Type: application/json' an that I have taken care in Karate as well. Curl requests looks like - curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/getPricingCalculation/getRoE \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: b52c9af3-bf68-4ec0-94d1-e46527db995e' \
  -d '{
  "credRelFreeIncome": 10,
  "interestIncome": 2,
  "internalExpectedLoss": 3,
  "nonCredIncome": 5
}'

Comment: I give up ! the only difference I see is the `charset=UTF-8` part so you can try add `* configure charset = null` - all the best :) maybe someone else who has a better idea of what's going on can help :P

Comment: I tried adding * configure charset = null and in response and now content-type was wthout charset=UTF-8 but still it was 403 forbidden error. How can Creator of Karate give up so easily!!!  :)

Comment: I guarantee you, if you give me a public end point where the cURL request works, I will solve this in 5 minutes. your move.

Comment: Issue was resolved when i commented below line in karate-config.js - karate.configure('proxy', 'myworkingproxy:8080')